# How to design RESTful search/filtering?

Tags: rest, search

I'm currently designing and implementing a RESTful API in PHP. However, I have been unsuccessful implementing my initial design.

```
GET /users # list of users
GET /user/1 # get user with id 1
POST /user # create new user
PUT /user/1 # modify user with id 1
DELETE /user/1 # delete user with id 1
```

So far pretty standard, right?

My problem is with the first one `GET /users`. I was considering sending parameters in the request body to filter the list. This is because I want to be able to specify complex filters without getting a super long url, like:

```
GET /users?parameter1=value1&parameter2=value2&parameter3=value3&parameter4=value4
```

Instead I wanted to have something like:

```
GET /users
# Request body:
{
    "parameter1": "value1",
    "parameter2": "value2",
    "parameter3": "value3",
    "parameter4": "value4"
}
```

which is much more readable and gives you great possibilities to set complex filters.

Anyway, `file_get_contents('php://input')` didn't return the request body for `GET` requests. I also tried `http_get_request_body()`, but the shared hosting that I'm using doesn't have `pecl_http`. Not sure it would have helped anyway.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body) and realized that GET probably isn't supposed to have a request body. It was a bit inconclusive, but they advised against it.

**So now I'm not sure what to do. How do you design a RESTful search/filtering function?**

I suppose I could use `POST`, but that doesn't seem very RESTful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RESTful URL design for search](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search)

Comment: Be careful!!! GET method must be IDEMPOTENT, and must be "cacheable".

If you send information in the body How can the system cache your request? 

HTTP allows caching GET request using only the URL, not the request body.

For instance, this two requests:

http://example.com
{
   test:"some"
}

http://example.com
{
   anotherTest:"some2"
}

are considered the same by the cache system: Both of them have exactly the same URL

Comment: Just to add, you should POST to the /users (collection) and not /user (single user).

Comment: Another point to consider is most app servers have access logs that logs the url and so might be anything in between. So there might be some un-intended info leak on GET.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234363/rest-search-interface-and-the-idempotency-of-get This is a useful resource (pun unintended): https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2.2

Answer (score 471):

The best way to implement a RESTful search is to consider the search itself to be a resource.  Then you can use the POST verb because you are creating a search.  You do not have to literally create something in a database in order to use a POST.

For example:

```
Accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
POST http://example.com/people/searches
{
  "terms": {
    "ssn": "123456789"
  },
  "order": { ... },
  ...
}
```

You are creating a search from the user's standpoint.  The implementation details of this are irrelevant.  Some RESTful APIs may not even need persistence.  That is an implementation detail.

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer by the OP. It is the most correct response to the question. @jason-harrelson is spot-on by saying that persistence is not needed to support the intended use of POST. The nice part about using POST, for a search resource, is the ability to use this as a future feature like saved searches, or suggested searches for a user of your API.

Comment: One significant limitation to using a POST request for a search endpoint is that it cannot be bookmarked.  Bookmarking search results (particularly complex queries) can be quite useful.

Comment: I wonder if it's then possible to have the PRG pattern for a post-redirect-get.

Comment: Searches, by their nature, are transient: data evolves between two searches with the same parameters, so I think that a GET request does not map cleanly to the search pattern. Instead, the search request should be POST (/Resource/search), then you can save that search and redirect to a search result, e.g. /Resource/search/iyn3zrt. That way, GET requests succeed and make sense.

Comment: I don't think post is suitable method for searching, data for normal GET requests could vary over time too.

Comment: what about how GitHub does it.  I like how they spit it out into resources still but I guess if you're doing a Google-like free text search you cant' really split that out into concrete resources in the url.  GitHub does it something like this: /search/[resourceName]?q=John...  where q is the keyword or whatever the text was typed into the search box but you're searching for a specific resource type in this case

Comment: Might as well just dump all verbs, and use POST for everything... But seriously, if we were to extrapolate this logic, then all dynamic pages should be retrieved using POST instead of GET, because we're creating a new (and potentially unique) HTML / JSON / whatever document with every request. Can't believe this answer has so many upvotes.

Comment: @OlegsJeremejevs: it's said that GETs should be idempotent (always return same results) - search will obviously return different results at different time. Now, /search isn't a resource at all, I'd say. I would put that under filtering the actual /users (or whatever) endpoint, what do you think?

Comment: @Zlatko: Think of `GET /users` - you'd need pagination for that, right? Pagination is a type of search / filter too, since you pass some parameters in and get a subset of resources. Does that warrant `POST`?

Comment: Exactly what I'm thinking. That's why I also think POST is wrong here. Search should just be a filter on `GET /resource` calls.

Comment: @OlegsJeremejevs Idempotent doesn't mean "always return same results". Otherwise I could never GET from any resource or collection which also accepts POSTs or PUTs

Comment: @OlegsJeremejevs "Might as well just dump all verbs, and use POST for everything" I'm not sure what you mean. Here we're posting to a collection (searches) to create a new resource (search) in that collection. Isn't that what it's usually used for?

Comment: This is absolutely the worst possible answer. I can't believe it has so many upvotes. This answer explains why: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/233164/how-do-searches-fit-into-a-restful-interface

Comment: After going through the link posted by richard, I don't think POST is the right RESTful way.

Comment: I don't think GET with parameters is always the right choice. You might be searching by sensitive data, such as card numbers or SSNs, and it is safer to hide that information in POST body. Hiding everything in post data is a good way to prevent malicious attacks or to stop clever users from doing things they should not.

Comment: @jkerak You shouldn't have sensitive data like ssn's going over the wire at all anyway, especially for a search! Use a surrogate key or something not sensitive.

Comment: Using GET for search does not violate the idempotent nature of GET.  The point of 'idempotent 'in regards to REST is that calling that operation does not itself affect the resource.  Calling GET with params 10 times does not change the results.

Comment: Very creative answer: just think of the search as a resource and -poof- there is your justification for using POST instead of GET. Convenient but wrong, in my opinion.

Comment: @DiegoDeberdt Everything's a resource if you're brave enough. (sorry)

Comment: Facebook and Netflix said the hell with REST and creayed their own specs for querying. GraphQl and Falcor and tney are OSS.

Comment: Search or filtering should never be done using the POST verb. It's totally wrong!

Comment: So a lot of people are suggesting that POST is wrong. I normally use GET and the query string to specify my filters (encoding my filters for more complicated searches) but what if I wanted to check for the existence of a resource, or a user resource to be more specific by username and password, simulating login authentication? This is obviously sensitive data (password) I wouldn't want exposed. Should I post both pieces of data to an enpoint and return a matching resource? Should I create an RPC type call and return true/false or something?

Comment: I think ideally you'd have the client site receive the search as a GET so it can be bookmarked, but if there was a dedicated API server behind it, it would be best to POST the query. Knowing that not everyone has this architecture- its just a matter of deciding if you need the search url to be cachable/bookmarked or not.

Comment: Lots of opinions here.  Maybe the deciding factor should be the type of data you're searching against.  For example, it could be a file or a picture used to for comparing.  Or maybe the search text is too difficult to url encode.  Those seem like reasons to post the data.

Comment: That's possibly the most tenuous definition of a POST scenario I've ever heard.

Comment: It does not only break bookmarking. It also breaks navigation entirely - try to go back to search results. Awful experience. My rule of thumb is: never ever use POST without redirection to GET in a browser experience.

Comment: I suppose with SPAs we could build FrontEnd navigation with GET and BackEnd queries with POST. That way bookmarking still works but you must map the GET url to the POST query in FrontEnd. Just a thought seems like there is no consensus on the internet.

Comment: Caching won't be supported as HTTP allows caching GET request using only the URL, not the request body.

Comment: As others have mentioned, I see 3 problems with POST.  You will have problem with (i) people unable to bookmark the search, (ii) the browser's back button leading to unexpected behavior, (iii) caching the result with services like Redis, because that is URL dependent.  To me, (iii) was a deal breaker; way too much resource consumption.  I do not like ugly URLs either, but ultimately decided that was necessary evil given the current constraints.

Comment: It's really terrifying to see the number of programmers who think POST offers more "security" than GET. [It does not](https://stackoverflow.com/q/198462/5532169), in the same way base64 does not "encrypt" your data. Security through obscurity is no security at all.

Comment: @RoboRobok The OP is talking about a RESTful **API** and not a web site, so there is no navigation to break here, because none exists. With this in mind, there is also no issue with bookmarks, since one wouldn't bookmark an API URI either.

Comment: I find it interesting how many of the comments on this answer completely missed the words **RESTful API** in the OP's question, rendering any points regarding bookmarking or navigation moot.

Comment: @TomLint I was reffering to some other comment suggesting using a form with method set to POST and no redirection.

Comment: Yes. @richard said this is the worst possible answer and when I went to check his link nothing really applies to the OP question, is all problems with websites, not APIs

Comment: @GabrielBB did you read the accepted answer? It specifically addresses this question.

Comment: POST is only to create a resource on the server. Not to do a search.

Answer (score 213):

If you use the request body in a GET request, you're breaking the REST principle, because your GET request won't be able to be cached, because cache system uses only the URL.

What's worse, your URL can't be bookmarked, because the URL doesn't contain all the information needed to redirect the user to this page.

Use URL or Query parameters instead of request body parameters, e.g.:

```
/myapp?var1=xxxx&var2=xxxx
/myapp;var1=xxxx/resource;var2=xxxx
```

In fact, the HTTP RFC 7231 says that:

> A payload within a GET request message has no defined semantics; sending a payload body on a GET request might cause some existing implementations to reject the request.

For more information take a look [here](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#page-24).

Comment: Learn from my mistake - I designed an api using the accepted answer's suggestion (POSTing json), but am moving over to url parameters.  Bookmark-ability may be more important than you think. In my case, there was a need to direct traffic to certain search queries (ad campaign).  Also, using the history API makes more sense with URL parameters.

Comment: It depends on how its used. If you are linking to a URL that loads the page based on those parameters, it make sense, but if the main page is doing an AJAX call only to get the data based on filter parameters, you can't bookmark that anyway because its an ajax call and has no bearing.  Naturally, you could also bookmark a URL that when you go there builds up a filter and POSTs that to the ajax call and it would work just fine.

Comment: @DanielLorenz For the best user experience, the URL should still be changed through the History API in that case. I can't stand when a website doesn't allow using the browser back functionality to navigate to previous pages. And if it is a standard server side generated page the only way to make it bookmarkable would to use  a GET request. It seems that good ol' query parameters are the best solution.

Comment: @Nathan I think I misread this answer.  I was talking about using query string parameters in a get.  You should never use body parameters in a GET call because that would be completely useless.  I was talking more about a GET with query string could be used/bookmarked and then at startup of the page, you can use those parameters to build up a filter to POST, using those parameters to get the data.  History would still work fine in that scenario.

Comment: @DanielLorenz Ah okay that makes sense. I think I misunderstood what you were saying.

Comment: This is a good example of where people try to over-complicate things and fix or improve something that was never broken, and has worked simply and easily since the beginning of the web.

Answer (score 112):

It seems that resource filtering/searching can be implemented in a RESTful way. The idea is to introduce a new endpoint called `/filters/` or `/api/filters/`.

Using this endpoint *filter* can be considered as a resource and hence created via `POST` method. This way - of course - body can be used to carry all the parameters as well as complex search/filter structures can be created.

After creating such filter there are two possibilities to get the search/filter result.

1. A new resource with unique ID will be returned along with `201 Created` status code. Then using this ID a `GET` request can be made to `/api/users/` like:

   ```
   GET /api/users/?filterId=1234-abcd
   ```
2. After new filter is created via `POST` it won't reply with `201 Created` but at once with `303 SeeOther` along with `Location` header pointing to `/api/users/?filterId=1234-abcd`. This redirect will be automatically handled via underlying library.

In both scenarios two requests need to be made to get the filtered results - this may be considered as a drawback, especially for mobile applications. For mobile applications I'd use single `POST` call to `/api/users/filter/`.

*How to keep created filters?*

They can be stored in DB and used later on. They can also be stored in some temporary storage e.g. redis and have some TTL after which they will expire and will be removed.

*What are the advantages of this idea?*

Filters, filtered results are cacheable and can be even bookmarked.

Comment: well this should be the accepted answer. You don't violate REST principles and you can make long complex queries to resources. It's nice, clean and bookmark compatible.
The only additional drawback is the need for storing key/value pairs for created filters, and the already mentioned two request steps.

Comment: The only concern with this approach is, if you have date-time filters in query (or a constantly changing value). Then the number of filters to store in db (or cache) are innumerable.

Answer (score 21):

I think you should go with request parameters but only as long as there isn't an appropriate HTTP header to accomplish what you want to do. The [HTTP specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html) does not explicitly say, that GET can not have a body. However [this paper](http://www.w3.org/2001/tag/doc/whenToUseGet-20040321#safe) states:

> By convention, when GET method is
>   used, all information required to
>   identify the resource is encoded in
>   the URI. There is no convention in
>   HTTP/1.1 for a safe interaction (e.g.,
>   retrieval) where the client supplies
>   data to the server in an HTTP entity
>   body rather than in the query part of
>   a URI. This means that for safe
>   operations, URIs may be long.

Comment: ElasticSearch also does GET with body and works well!

Comment: Yeah but they control the server implementation may not be tne xase on the interwebs.

Answer (score 12):

As I'm using a [laravel/php](https://laravel.com) backend I tend to go with something like this:

```
/resource?filters[status_id]=1&filters[city]=Sydney&page=2&include=relatedResource
```

PHP automatically turns `[]` params into an array, so in this example I'll end up with a `$filter` variable that holds an array/object of filters, along with a page and any related resources I want eager loaded.

If you use another language, this might still be a good convention and you can create a parser to convert `[]` to an array.

Comment: This approach looks nice, but there could be issues with using square brackets in URLs, see [what-characters-can-one-use-in-a-url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649730/what-characters-can-one-use-in-a-url)

Comment: @Sky This could be avoided by URI encoding the `[` and `]`. Using encoded representations of these characters to group query parameters is a well known practice. It's even used in [JSON:API specification](https://jsonapi.org/format/#fetching-sparse-fieldsets).

Answer (score 4):

FYI: I know this is a bit late but for anyone who is interested.
Depends on how RESTful you want to be, you will have to implement your own filtering strategies as the HTTP spec is not very clear on this. I'd like to suggest url-encoding all the filter parameters e.g.

```
GET api/users?filter=param1%3Dvalue1%26param2%3Dvalue2
```

I know it's ugly but I think it's the most RESTful way to do it and should be easy to parse on the server side :)

Comment: I would not go for this approach as it has no clear arguments. The only readable argument here is filter which then has an URL encoded value. If you want to go for this approach, I would adjust this to GET api/users?mode=filter&paramA=valueA&paramB=valueB
that way you could have a mode=filter, mode=search, mode=exclude, ...

Comment: This is useful in case where there is huge amount (n) of possible params (which is not problem for front), but in backend with proposed approach you have just one param (filter) instead of n(huge num) optional params or dynmaic param handling.

Answer (score 1):

Don't fret too much if your initial API is fully RESTful or not (specially when you are just in the alpha stages). Get the back-end plumbing to work first. You can always do some sort of URL transformation/re-writing to map things out, refining iteratively until you get something stable enough for widespread testing ("beta").

You can define URIs whose parameters are encoded by position and convention on the URIs themselves, prefixed by a path you know you'll always map to something. I don't know PHP, but I would assume that such a facility exists (as it exists in other languages with web frameworks):

.ie. Do a "user" type of search with param[i]=value[i] for i=1..4 on store #1 (with value1,value2,value3,... as a shorthand for URI query parameters):

```
1) GET /store1/search/user/value1,value2,value3,value4
```

or

```
2) GET /store1/search/user,value1,value2,value3,value4
```

or as follows (though I would not recommend it, more on that later)

```
3) GET /search/store1,user,value1,value2,value3,value4
```

With option 1, you map all URIs prefixed with `/store1/search/user` to the search handler (or whichever the PHP designation) defaulting to do searches for resources under store1 (equivalent to `/search?location=store1&type=user`.

By convention documented and enforced by the API, parameters values 1 through 4 are separated by commas and presented in that order.

Option 2 adds the search type (in this case `user`) as positional parameter #1. Either option is just a cosmetic choice.

Option 3 is also possible, but I don't think I would like it. I think the ability of search within certain resources should be presented in the URI itself preceding the search itself (as if indicating clearly in the URI that the search is specific within the resource.)

The advantage of this over passing parameters on the URI is that the search is part of the URI (thus treating a search as a resource, a resource whose contents can - and will - change over time.) The disadvantage is that parameter order is mandatory.

Once you do something like this, you can use GET, and it would be a read-only resource (since you can't POST or PUT to it - it gets updated when it's GET'ed). It would also be a resource that only comes to exist when it is invoked.

One could also add more semantics to it by caching the results for a period of time or with a DELETE causing the cache to be deleted. This, however, might run counter to what people typically use DELETE for (and because people typically control caching with caching headers.)

How you go about it would be a design decision, but this would be the way I'd go about. It is not perfect, and I'm sure there will be cases where doing this is not the best thing to do (specially for very complex search criteria).

Comment: Yo, if you (someone, whoever/whatever) things approprite to downvote my answer, would it hurt you ego to at least put a comment indicating what exactly do you disagree with? I know it's the interweebz, but ... ;)

Comment: I didn't downvote, but the fact that the question starts with: "I'm currently designing and implementing a RESTful API" and your answer starts with "Don't fret too much if your initial API is fully RESTful or not" feels wrong to me. If you're designing an API you are designing an API. The question is asking how to best design the API, not about whether the API should be designed.

Comment: The API *is* the system, work on the API first, not the backend plumbing, the first implementation could/should just be a mock.   HTTP has a mechanism for passing parameters, you are suggesting it be reinvented, but worse (ordered parameters instead of name value pairs).   Hence the down vote.

Comment: @gardarh - yes, it feels wrong, but at times, it is pragmatic. The primary objective is to design an API that works for the business context at hand. If a fully RESTFULL approach is appropriate to the business at hand, then go for it. If it is not, then don't go for it. That is, design an API that meets your specific business requirements. Going around trying to make it RESTfull as its primary requirement is no much different from asking "how do I use the adapter pattern in X/Y problem." Don't shoe horn paradigms unless they solve actual, valuable problems.

Comment: @StevenHerod - I'm not reinventing anything. A resource's URI does not include the URL parameters, ergo  a need to represent a certain class of resources that might be "representable" as a collection of HTTP parameters and a base URI. There are no clean and nice approaches to do this *when you really need to do this.* How much or how little you want to represent a resource with a URI and HTTP parameters, that's specific to the problem at hand. Sometimes, YOU REALLY SHOULD NOT USE HTTP PARAMETERS TO REPRESENT A RESOURCE. Ergo, my suggestion of *an approach* (one of many) to deal with such cases

Comment: Consider the following two (contrived) cases: a URI for a collection of books by author X  vs a collection of books by topic Y. One could easily say "well, HTTP already has a mechanism for passing parameters", and we opt for /books?author=X and /books?topic=Y. If, on the other hand, we need RESTfull URIs, then we might need something like /books/author/X and /books/topic/Y. Then what happens when we need to represent the intersection of these two? With HTTP parameters, it is quite easy. With a RESTful requirement for complex cases, it is not that simple (/books/X/topic/Y? /books/Y/author/X?)

Comment: So, there is no clean, generic answer. To pretend there is one, or to pretend that the problem does not exist because "HTTP already has a mechanism for passing parameters", that makes no sense at all.

Comment: I view a resource as some collection of state, and parameters as a means for manipulating the representation of that state parametrically. Think of it this way, if you could use knobs and switches to adjust how the resource is displayed (show/hide certain bits of it, order it differently, etc...) those controls are params. If it's actually a different resource ('/albums' vs '/artists', for instance), that's when it should be represented in the path. That's what is intuitive to me, anyway.

Comment: "Get the back-end plumbing to work first".  That's an inside-out approach.  For me I do BDD and TDD and so I go outside in which starts with the story from the PM.  Doing it this way guides you to code for the business requirement which is a much better way to go about this.  And doing it this way makes sure you're coding lean and only to the behavior asked in the story.  Don't go stubbing a bunch of crap out in the backend.  TDD forces you to go lean by going this route..believe me.   It's MORE important to think about your REST api from the outside-in perspective as they tie to requirements

Comment: I like the mature pragmatism of this answer, I think OP may find it conveys a useful approach to evaluating his/her own eventual solution.  Plus, I like that this answer shows a way to do search/filter as a kind of GET, which feels a lot less pedantic that having to treat it as creating a kind of (generic, transient) resource.  I want my service to focus on the persistent resources in my app domain, not ones imposed by the architectural framework.

Comment: Funny how people will argue to death about a principle. Facebook and Netflix said the hell with it and created GraphQL and Falcor. Just because its http and an api doesn't mean it has to be REST.

Comment: ^^ Bingo. Finally someone who gets it.

Comment: Standardization is there for some purpose. It makes things intuitive. Otherwise every person  who looks at API need to go through long description on how to decode it. Standardization should only be broken in exception cases if following it adds more cons than pros. Not sure how the URI scheme suggested is any better than the one mentioned in the question it self. I can see many  standards broken without adding any value.

Comment: @kishorborate - and I've seen people sticking to the standards like religion without considering other requirements, losing significant value (rather than adding.) It gets tiring after a while.

We do development/engineering, the act of finding middle ground when one cannot (or should not) stick to a kosher standard. Standards are guidelines for general case scenarios, nothing more.

Comment: @luis.espinal i totally feel you, I see more and more almost anyone trying to write "cool" code they just read about in a book forgetting about their purpose. Most of the time it is overengineering that only brings complexity and problems.