# What characters can one use in a URL?

Tags: url, rfc

I have an application that takes all the parameters in the url like this: `/category/subcategory/sub-subcategory`. I want to be able to give out extra parameters at the end of the URL, like `page-2/order-desc`. This would make the whole URL into `cat/subcat/sub-subcat{delimiting-character}page-2/order-desc`.

My question is: what characters could I use as `{delimiting-character}`. I tend to prefer ":" as I know for sure it will never appear anyplace else but I don't know if it would be standard compliant or at least if it will not give me problems in the future.

As I recall vimeo used something like this: `vimeo.com/video:{code}` but they seem to have changed this.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use alphanumeric, plus the special characters "$-_.+!*'(),"
More info here: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Also, take note not to exceed 2000 characters in url

Comment: The `+` sign is a bit of a tricky one - this ought always to be properly encoded, and even then...

Comment: @andrew Many thanks for this... I have been using the tilde (~) in my URLs for years as a delimeter for data. I just learnt that there's a risk in doing this from your RFC URL. Thanks and +1 for this finding.

Comment: Here's that text from the URL: **Other characters are unsafe because
   gateways and other transport agents are known to sometimes modify
   such characters. These characters are "{", "}", "|", "\", "^", "~","[", "]", and "`"**

Comment: @GrantThomas Can you give evidence for your statement that the ```+``` sign is an exception?

Comment: @Marcus I've seen browsers and servers use + as an encoding for spaces even though there already exists a urlencoding for them. Unless I'm mistaken and that's just pretty-printing, it may be a common deviation from the spec. As a result, I've taken to percent encoding anything that I want to be a text literal. If I want a literal +, then I encode it. No evidence given, so none required to ignore this advice.

Answer (score 8):

The most recent URI spec is RFC 3986; see [the ABNF](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#appendix-A) for details on what characters are allowed in which parts for the URI.

The format for an absolute path part is:

```
  path-absolute = "/" [ segment-nz *( "/" segment ) ]
  segment       = *pchar
  segment-nz    = 1*pchar
  pchar         = unreserved / pct-encoded / sub-delims / ":" / "@"
  pct-encoded   = "%" HEXDIG HEXDIG
  unreserved    = ALPHA / DIGIT / "-" / "." / "_" / "~"
  sub-delims    = "!" / "$" / "&" / "'" / "(" / ")"
                      / "*" / "+" / "," / ";" / "="
```

Answer (score 2):

See http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt

Basically, you are allowed all aphanumerics as well as `$ - _ . + ! * ' ( ) ,`

Comment: thanks! I'll go with "." as the other look a bit out of place in a URL (and _ and - might appear in other places in my URL). :)

Answer (score 1):

If you use dash or underscore, remember that a dash is read by Google as a hyphen, so does not alter how your URL is categorized.  An underscore is counted as a character, and can mess up your SEO.

Ex: dash-use = dash use (2 words);
underscore_use = underscore_use (1 word)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a dash or an underscore (these are used frequently).  You could use any character you want to but for example, spaces turn into %20 in the url so they don't look too-nice.