# Display Iframe with colorbox, url with parameters does not work

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, colorbox

I'm new to the site so please forgive me if I make some mistakes. And I'm also sorry about my bad English.

I'm trying to display an Iframe Colorbox from a dropdown list, it works well like this:

```
<?php 
foreach($entities as $entity => $value) 
 {
   echo '<option value="'. $value .'" class="iframe" href="http://mysite/index.php">'. $entity .'</option>';
 }
 ?>
```

However, if I try to use some URL with parameters like:

`mysite/index.php?title=Special:UserLogin&returntoquery=mobileaction%3Dtoggle_view_mobile`

The Iframe will not show anymore. Can anyone please tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you show how you are trying to display the iframe?

Comment: I'm using colorbox:http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/. I just added this to the header:                                <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.colorbox-min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){    
$(".iframe").colorbox({iframe:true, width:"80%", height:"80%"});
    });
 </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont think you can use :(Colon) in your URL(except port) as I have seen previously.([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5649730/what-characters-can-one-use-in-a-url))

Can u change that and take a look?

Comment: Thank you! I removed the colon and it actually worked. However what I need to display is some URL like index.php?title=Special:UserLogin, so how can I add the colon to my URL?

Comment: I think you are using ci(or any framework) here. There should be a config file where there is  $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-+'; stated. Add  Colon there if its not added. Also is my first answer accepted?