# ? in url to match with react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have 
`<Route path="/\?Code" exact component={GameBoard}/>`

in routes but It won't routes with url: /?Code

I have tried even `<Route path="/?Code" exact component={GameBoard}/>`

without escaping. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Escaping the `?` will not help you because there are some restrictions on what can be used in URLs (one of which being the symbols we can we use in structuring them)

For example the allowed symbols include all alphabets , numericals and some special characters .`- $ . +!*` etc 
For a deep dive you can refer [this](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt): 
and for more answers you can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5649730/9312233)