# Flask: Implementing a HTTP GET with an array parameter

Tags: http, rest, flask, payload, rfc2616

I am implementing an HTTP REST API which contains a `/feed` request. The request returns a user's news feed.

The request comes with a few parameters, including the `userId`, a list of followers, `startTime` and `maxItems`.

The easiest way to implement it on the server side (Python and Flask) would be adding a JSON payload, from which I can read the arguments.

Alas, adding a payload to a `GET` request [is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body), and it is no supported by many client libraries.

My options:

- Making `/feed` a `POST` request. It is ugly, because `POST` shouldn't be used to request information from a server.
- Splitting the `/feed` call to `/updateFollowers` (`POST`) and `/feed` (`GET`). It would waste time because the `GET` call can be made only after the `POST` call.

Both options seem wrong. Is there any standard way to make a `GET`-like call with a bunch of complex arguments?

Comment: REST doesn't really have rules as you are probably aware but I'd like to share my opinion with you: It's also quite ugly to put 'request types' in the resource like this `/getFeed`, I would just stick with `/feed`. Apart from that instead of passing the user as a parameter to `/feed` it might be better to construct your url like `/users/<userId>/feed` but that kind of depends on the implementation of the rest of your service

Comment: @TimCastelijns the `getFeed` was a mistake - it's really `/feed`. Apart from that, `userId` is OK for a URL parameter - but how do I pass arrays in the URL?

Comment: In that case using POST might not be such a bad idea. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering

Comment: @TimCastelijns Seems about right. Would you like to post it as a full answer so I can upvote/accept it?

Comment: Since you must use a bunch of complex arguments, a POST request makes sense. I don't think there is any rule that says POST must never be used for read operations. However, I would ask you if there is a way you can minimize the arguments in your example. What if you just send the "userid" in GET request and let the server determine their followers etc ? For max entries, you could possibly add it to the GET request with something like /feed/<userid>/<startTime><maxItems> where startTime and maxItems could be optional and flask view will default them to something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Splitting the /feed call to /updateFollowers (POST) and /feed (GET).
>   It would waste time because the GET call can be made only after the
>   POST call.

REST doesn't really have rules as you are probably aware but I'd like to share my opinion with you: It's quite ugly to put 'request type verbs' in the resource like this, so I wouldn't do this.

> Making /feed a POST request. It is ugly, because POST shouldn't be
>   used to request information from a server.

I understand why you think this is ugly. It sounds wrong to get data using a POST request, however, as stated in [this question's top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering):

> The best way to implement a RESTful search is to consider the search
>   itself to be a resource. Then you can use the POST verb because you
>   are creating a search. You do not have to literally create something
>   in a database in order to use a POST.

Since this is similiar to what you're doing, using POST might not be such a bad idea. I don't see a better alternative so you probably want to implement it like this.

Comment: `POST`-ing a search does not make a lot of sense to me, but it's probably the lesser of (quite a few) evils.

Comment: @AdamMatan *it's probably the lesser of (quite a few) evils* I think so, yeah. You can make it make a little more sense by thinking like this *consider the search itself to be a resource* though