# HTTP GET or POST for this?

Tags: web-services, http, rest

I am writing a RESTful API specification and there's an API that needs a bunch of input data to do a query and return some results. It behaves like a GET because you're just asking for information, but because you need to provide a bunch of request data, it seems like it should a POST.

Any thoughts?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering

Comment: Please describe in more detail what the "bunch of input data" is and how it is used to perform the query. Do they filter the result?

Comment: It's a bunch of data that the API will use to do a search and say if there were any matching results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send a form then use `POST`. It may be easier to handle it in eventual HTTP clients.

I usually use `GET` if I want to keep my query parameters in URL, so it could be copied and used somewhere else and executed with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to create a "RESTful" API, then you should conform to the typical conventions for HTTP methods:

- GET - List/retrieve item or collection (safe to call without changes)
- POST - Create/insert a new entry or collection (will change data)
- PUT - Replace/update an entry or collection (will change data, but can be called multiple times safely)
- DELETE - delete item or collection

So even if you have 50 parameters for your query, use HTTP GET.

For developers using the RESTful style, these are the assumed behaviors-- if they see POST, they will assume you are inserting a record or records.

Wikipedia entry has a little table which you can print and tape on your wall:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer