# Using POST or GET for a WebAPI Action method that returns a list, but requires params

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-core

Currently I have the following standard functions in each of my controllers to handle basic CRUD operations:

```
GET /api/todo           Get all to-do items
GET /api/todo/{id}      Get an item by ID
POST /api/todo          Add a new item
PUT /api/todo/{id}      Update an existing item
DELETE /api/todo/{id}   Delete an item
```

However, the time came where I realized I actually need to pass multiple parameters to get a list of todo items that is filtered at the database level rather than retrieving all of the items and using linq.

**For example here is how I decided to go about it:**
In my Controller:

```
// POST: api/todo
[HttpPost]
public IList<TodoItem> Get([FromBody]GetTodoItemsRequest request)
{
    return _todoItemManager.GetTodoItems(request.Name, request.CategoryId);
}
```

As you can see I created a new Model called GetTodoItemsRequest which will have a property for each of my parameters. In this case: Name, CategoryId.

I figured when dealing with multiple parameters and retrieving a list it is best to do POST and create a model specifically for it. Rather than using a GET and passing all kinds of information in the url.

It seems a bit strange to be doing the above... Would msot see it as a perfectly fine solution or is there something I am missing in the WebAPI world?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering, discusses this exact point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe that is semantically incorrect to use `POST` method for a simple read operation, even if you need a complex model. You are doing a pure query on your resource called `todo`, and this should really be a `GET` operation for many reasons:

1. It should be **cachable**: `POST` request aren't cachable by their nature, and caching is an important constraint in RESTful services.
2. It should semantically indicate that **no side-effect will be raised** from the call: `GET` requests must be **idempotent** and **safe**, `POST` operations, instead, indicate some kind of data manipulation. Your operation (filtering) is both idempotent and safe, so it should be spontaneously represented by a `GET` request.
3. The part of the URI after a `?` character is called query string for a reason: it represent parameters that further specify the *scope* of a request. Well, isn't filtering results just an example of this approach?

Apart from that, it seems to me that, if `Name` and `CategoryId` are required parameters for your query, your filtering operation could be better represented by another URI in which `Name` and `CategoryId` are turned into route parameters:

```
http://yourhost.com/api/users/{name}/categories/{categoryId}/todos
```

Assuming a relationship between your `name` parameter (a user name maybe?) and the `categories`.

If, instead, your parameters are completely optional, then leaving them as query string parameters is the best choice:

```
http://yourhost.com/api/todos?name=nameValue&categoryId=categoryIdValue
```

---

A side note:
you should really use plural for your resources if they represents a collection of items: e.g. `api/todo` will return an array of todos, so you should rename it into `api/todos`.