# What HTTP method to use when querying a collection by IDs

Tags: api, rest, http, collections

What HTTP method should I use if I want to query a collection for the given IDs that possibly go over 500 items. Like:

```
GET /api/v2.0/collection/?ids=1,2,3,4,5,6...
```

Query param is not gonna look good with over 500 items. and `GET` doesn't have a Content-Size. `POST` seems not a good fit since I'm just fetching the resources selectively. What would you great programmers do? Do you know any public example I can check?

Comment: how about range in query params 1-199?

Comment: @SMA, ids are not numbers. Nor they are sequential.

Comment: It seems that this is just filtering/searching, please have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to deal with a situation like this is to make the ids collection into their own resource.
For example, you can create a selector resource to which you can `POST` the ids like:

```
POST /api/v2.0/selectors
[1,2,3,4,5,6,...]
```

The `POST` request would return a selector `<id>`, which you can use to query the collection resource like:

```
GET /api/v2.0/collections?selector=<id>
```