# Best practice for filtering results from a RESTful API call?

Tags: rest, api-design

I'm defining a RESTful API for a TV broadcaster, specifically what the path should look like when asking for a subset of data. For example if I wanted to get the whole content for a particular channel, language on that channel between a specific date, how would I filter by date? The path below seems too long:

```
endpoint.com/content/channels/{channel_name}/language/french/from/20160701/to/20160801
```

An alternative I saw is to 'treat the search as a resource' and POST the date range filters to it in the request body, as mentioned here on SO: ([How to design RESTful search/filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering))

Any thoughts?

Comment: Why don't you use query parameters for anything beyond {channel_name} ?

Comment: Don't use path parameters like that.

Answer (score 1):

I also work for a TV Broadcaster and the approach we have taken is to post the search criteria through a resource. Much easier to handle and doesn't create an endless path.

Interface :

```
@POST
@Path("/lookup")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
List<Content> getContent(CriteriaSearch cr);
```

Implementation :

```
@Override
@Public
public List<ContentInfo> getContent(CriteriaSearch searchCriteria) {

        List<ContentInfo> contentInfos = contentManager.lookupContent(searchCriteria);
```

...

Comment: Could you illustrate with an example?

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you use `@QueryParam` annotation to filter your resources by getting it from URI.

To filter the resource you can use an URI like

```
/channel_name?language=french&from=20160701&to=20160801
```

Using JAX-RS you then can access the these values:

```
@GET
@Path("/channel_name")
List<Content> getContent(@QueryParam("language")String lang,
                         @QueryParam("from")Long from, 
                         @QueryParam("to")Long to) {
  // your logic
}
```

Of course you need to take care of exceptions and the repsonse including status codes in this case.

Comment: Why POST to *get* content? That looks like RPC, not REST.

Comment: OK. The URL does not match the `@Path@`.

Comment: this is not the actual solution for application..its just a way to design REST api to overcome given problem -see 'can'. Hope its match :)