# How to design a query where I retrieve last data from resource that I want to apply filter to in RESTful way?

Tags: rest, api, http, design-patterns

How should a query look like when I want to retrieve last `measurements` from `installations` that aren't removed?

Something like that?

```
/my-web-service/installations/measurements/last?removed=false
```

The thing is, I don't want to retrieve last `measurements` that weren't removed from `installations`. I want to retrieve last `measurements` from `installations` that weren't removed.

Comment: What is the relation here between installations and measurements?

Comment: One installation can have many measurements.

Comment: Here I want to retrieve all last measurements from all installations (that aren't removed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a couple possibilities here:

1. If you need to read the data from the endpoint *transactionally*, the way you designed it is the way to go. What I'd change is the name of the param from `removed` to `installationRemoved` since it's more descriptive and shorten the endpoint to `/my-web-service/measurements/` - since with `installations` it's unclear in which scope does the client operate. Also, don't you need `since` param to filter the *last* measurements?
2. It there's a chance to split the two endpoints I'd add:

   - `/my-web-service/installations/?removed=false`
   - `/my-web-service/measurements/?since=timestamp&installations=<array>`

   It does not make it better (when it comes to better or worse) but easier and more predictive for the users.

In general try to add more general endpoints with filtering options rather then highly dedicated - doing one particular thing. This way leads to hard to use, loose API. Also, on [filtering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering).

And final notice, your API is good if your clients use it not because they have to but when they like it ;)

Comment: At first, shouldn't it be `measurements?since=` rather than `measurements/?since=`?
And the second thing is, should I have an array in my url in the form of `&installations=[1, 2, 3]` or `&installation=1&installation=2&installation=3`?

Comment: @Defozo, it should definitely end with slash, always ;) When it comes to the latter, it depends on your technology stack (not being very demanding to implement), and well known standards - so it seems that it should be: `installation=1&installation=2&installation=3` when it comes to how arrays are handled in HTTP query params.

Comment: @Defozo, it's up to you ;) I always end the endpoints with slash.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I found your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering where you doesn't use slash at the end and thought that you just kidding me here :D

Answer (score 1):

According to [this best practices article](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api#advanced-queries), you could use "aliases for common queries":

> To make the API experience more pleasant for the average consumer,
>   consider packaging up sets of conditions into easily accessible
>   RESTful paths. For example, the recently closed tickets query above
>   could be packaged up as GET /tickets/recently_closed

So, in your case, it could be:

```
/my-web-service/installations/non_removed/measurements/last
```

where `non_removed` would be an alias for querying installations that weren't removed.

Hope it helps!