# Is a 404 http code appropriate when a successful REST query gives 0 results?

Tags: rest, api, http-response-codes

We had a bit of a heated debate at work this week regarding the proper use of HTTP error code 404.  I feel that it is being used inappropriately in this situation, and they insist that "this is how it is everywhere".

Here's the scenario:
We have a REST API endpoint with a static URI like "https://server.domain.com/restapi/getnode" that accepts a json body during a POST operation to see if a server exists within the database.   There is 1 server allowed per query.
The way it is designed, if the server exists, it returns http code 200 with the body of the message being the details of the server within the database.  If it doesn't exist, then they return a 404 code with the message "server x is not found in database y".

I feel that this is incorrect because according to the standards from [W3C](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) 4xx codes are for client-related issues, and 404 is specifically if the server can not server up that specific URI.  Further, this is not really an error, we would not only expect the occasional negative/empty response as part of the normal business, but that is expected to be the state on the majority of the calls.

Their response to this is that according to sources such as [AWS REST Standards](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/amazon-drive/ad-restful-api-response-codes.html) and [ServiceNow REST Standards](https://docs.servicenow.com/integrate/inbound_rest/reference/r_RESTAPIHTTPResponseCodes.html) that 404 is appropriate because the query didn't find the server, therefore it couldn't find the resource (To which I feel that they are misinterpreting the term "resource").

So, who is correct here?  Or is this more of a gray area than I think it is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relevant part of the specification here is [Client Error 4xx](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5).

> Except when responding to a HEAD request, the server SHOULD send a representation containing an explanation of the error situation, and whether it is a temporary or permanent condition.
>
> User agents SHOULD display any included representation to the user.

In other words, the status code is meta data that indicates to general-purpose components that the payload of the response is an explanation of the error, and not a representation of the resource.

If what you are actually doing is returning a representation of the resource which is at this moment an empty list, then you should be using a Successful code, not a Client Error code.

For example, if we have a resource that lists women who have been sworn into the office of President of the United States, the expression of that resource, as of 2019-09-25, would be an empty list.  So a standard HTTP response would look like

```
200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

[]
```

On the other hand, this response says something completely different

```
404 Not Found
Content-Type: application/json

[]
```

What this says is that there was no current representation of the requested resource, and the representation *of the explanation* of the problem is an empty list, so please show an empty list to the user so that they know what to do.

Comment: That said, I don't believe that being right is actually going to win you the argument; particularly in the circumstances that you described.

Answer (score 1):

This is a neverending debate with no useful outcome. See for example [How to design RESTful search/filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering), [Do web applications use HTTP as a transport layer, or do they count as an integral part of the HTTP server?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/270821/do-web-applications-use-http-as-a-transport-layer-or-do-they-count-as-an-integr) (disclaimer: my question), and thousands of other questions on the Stack Exchange network and thousands of blogs like "which status code to pick for REST scenario XYZ".

The fact that you're using POST for a request with GET semantics, means you're already not properly applying REST. POST is used to create resources, not to find existing resources. If you have a "servers"  resource collection, then you're dealing with "server" resources.

If you want to have a "find-server" endpoint, and you want to use POST to "create" a "find-server resource result", which you can then issue a GET request to to obtain your search results, you're a masochist who tries to shoehorn an application into a design philosophy that doesn't fit the problem domain.

So just be pragmatic. Does the endpoint exist? Yes, so 404 is not applicable. Return a 200 (the resource exists, the request is correct) with an body indicating no results were found, or a 204 ("no content") without a body.