# File export HTTP endpoint GET vs POST

Tags: javascript, rest, http, post, get

I'm building a REST API endpoint that creates an Excel file export and I'm wondering if this should be a GET or POST request. I can think of several reasons to do either.

In general I'd use GET for fetching data and POST for creation, but this seems to be a bit of a grey area.

This endpoint will be called from JS on button click so there is no limitation there for either one or the other.

**Reasons to use GET:**

- The file is not stored anywhere, so no state is updated on the server.
- The endpoint could be bookmarked (although it's not a requirement).

**Reasons to use POST:**

- Technically something gets created, so the action is not idempotent even though nothing is saved.
- In the future complex filters might be added which could get complex if these have to be added in the query string.
- The response might change on consecutive requests so it cannot be cached.

What's the recommended HTTP request method in this scenario?

Comment: this might be worth a read where it says filtering is really creating a search object https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What's the recommended HTTP request method in this scenario?

If the request is essentially read only, then you should use [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9110.html#name-get).

> The response might change on consecutive requests so it cannot be cached.

That matters less than you might expect, because the server controls the [caching metadata](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc9111.html).  So if you want the client to ask for a fresh copy every time, you just tune the headers appropriately.

The fact that the response isn't cacheable doesn't change the semantics of the *request*.

> In the future complex filters might be added which could get complex if these have to be added in the query string.

Practical answer: worry about that when you get there.

Yes, if you give the client code enough options, it will eventually become impractical to capture all of those options in the target-uri; at that point, you may need to change to a protocol that communicates the options in the request-body, at which point you'll need to give up on GET as the method-token that communicates those options to the server.