# How to name REST resource for similar endpoints (findById / findByEmail)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, api, rest

I have 2 endpoints as shown below, but I cannot use the endpoint urls like this:

```
@GetMapping("/{email}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> findByEmail(@PathVariable String email) {
}
```

```
@GetMapping("/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Void> findById(@PathVariable long id) {
}
```

Should I use something like `@GetMapping("mail/{email}")` ?

Comment: Start with something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering).  Whatever approach is taken, be consistent!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, using a different path for each endpoint is a good way to avoid conflicts. You can use @GetMapping annotation with a unique path for each endpoint, for example @GetMapping("/email/{email}") for findByEmail method and @GetMapping("/id/{id}") for findById method.

Therefore, when a request comes in as URL /{email} or /{id}, the Spring framework can distinguish between these two endpoints based on different path values.