# Proper RESTful way to handle a request that is not really creating or getting something?

Tags: rest

I am writing a little app that does one thing only: takes some user-provided data, does some analysis on it, and returns a "tag" for that data. I am thinking that the client should either `GET` or `POST` their request to `/getTag` in order to get a response back.

Nothing is stored on the server when the client does this, so it feels weird to use a POST. However, there is not a uniform URI for the analysis either, so using a GET feels weird, since it will return different things depending on what data is provided.

What is the best way to represent this functionality with REST?

Answer (score 2):

The "best way" is to do whatever is most appropriate for your application and its needs. Not knowing that, here are a few ideas:

1. `GET` is the most appropriate verb since you're not creating or storing anything on the server, just retrieving something that the server provides.
2. Don't put the word `get` in the URI as you've suggested. Verbs like that are already provided by HTTP, so just use `/tag` and `GET` it instead.
3. You should use a well-understood (or "cool") URI for this resource and pass the data as query parameters. I wouldn't worry about it feeling weird (see [this question's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234363/rest-search-interface-and-the-idempotency-of-get/) answers to find out why).

To sum up, just `GET` on `/tag?foo=bar&beef=dead`, and you're done.

Answer (score 1):

POST can represent performing an action. The action doesn't *have* to be a database action.

What you have really created is a Remote Procedure. RPC is usually all POST. I don't think this is a good fit for REST, but that doesn't have to stop you from using simple URLs and JSON.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like there would probably be a reason you or the user who generated the original data would want the generated tag to persist, wouldn't they?

If that's a possibility, then I'd write it as `POST /tags` and pass the `/tags/:id` resource URI back as a Location: header.

If I really didn't care about persisting the generated tag, I'd think about what the "user-generated data" was and how much processing is happening behind the scenes. If the "tag" is different enough from whatever data is being passed into the system, `GET /tag` might be really confusing for an API consumer.

Answer (score 0):

I'll second Brian's answer: use a `GET`. If the same input parameters return the same output, and you're not really creating anything, it's an idempotent action and thus perfectly suited for a `GET`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `GET` and `POST` either:

- `GET /tag?data="..." -> 200, tag`

  > The GET method means retrieve whatever information (in the form of an
  >   entity) is identified by the Request-URI. If the Request-URI refers to
  >   a data-producing process, it is the produced data which shall be
  >   returned as the entity in the response and not the source text of the
  >   process, unless that text happens to be the output of the process.
- `POST /tag {data: "..."} -> 200, tag`

  > The action performed by the POST method might not result in a resource
  >   that can be identified by a URI. In this case, either 200 (OK) or 204
  >   (No Content) is the appropriate response status, depending on whether
  >   or not the response includes an entity that describes the result.

according to the HTTP standard / [method definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) section.

I would use `GET` if I were you (and `POST` only if you want to send files).