# How to Support Parameters with Play Mini's REST?

Tags: playframework, akka, play2-mini

I'm using Akka and Play Mini (which is just a REST layer on top of Netty). I'm using it from Java. The syntax is simple, covered in their readme on GitHub:

```
    @URL("/coco/*/name/*")
```

This is working fine, but means that all URLs will have to be only long paths. I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search) that has some people claiming parameters are verboten and others saying they absolutely are not. I wish the play docs just stated their position, but alas. I am looking for the ability to support a url in the format of:

```
    /search/query=dogs
```

Maybe the regular Play docs address this. Will keep searching..

Comment: How about this pattern..http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sw

Comment: Yeah, that format is the same as mine, but just a different parameter name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this will help other people.

```
@URL("/hello/*\\?*")
public static Result show() {
    Map<String, String[]> queryString = request().queryString();

    Map<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
    for (String key : queryString.keySet()) {
        for (String value : queryString.get(key)) {
            data.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    response().setContentType("text/html");
    return ok(data.toString());
}
```

If you test with: `curl "http://localhost:9000/hello/test?param1=0&param2=yes"`

The result will be:

```
test{param1=0, param2=yes}
```