# REST route for alternative Get query type of calls

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api

I am using .NET Web API and need a strategy for route creation of queries.  For example, say from the page the code is at a decision point and needs direction from business logic on the server about how to proceed.

Just for review this route will return a standard user...

```
http://mysite/api/user/5
```

However, if I want to know if the user has some characteristic determined by business logic which I would make a UI decision on, what would a good REST call be for something like this?

Maybe...

```
http://mysite/api/user/5?canbake=true
```

Or is this better...

```
http://mysite/api/user/5/canbake
```

And if the latter, then what does the route definition look like to make that happen?

Comment: I like the querystring method - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the general consensus is that the latter is better.
That said, the  route definition would look something like:

```
public static void RegisterApiRoutes(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name:"UserApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}/{bake}",
        defaults: new 
            {
                bake = RouteParameter.Optional
            });
}
```