# Method overloading in WebAPI

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am developing a RESTful web service by WebAPI, I need to overload one of my methods, for example:

```
[HttpGet]
public void Send(string body, string phoneNumber)
```

and

```
 [HttpGet]
  public void Send(string body, [FromUri] List<string> phoneNumber)
```

When I call this service by using this address :

http://webservice.com/api/send?body=Hello&phoneNumber=1345456,123123

the first method is called but I prefer to call the second method by using this address:

http://webservice.com/api/send?body=Hello&phoneNumber=134556&phoneNumber=123123

but the first method is called again!

Is it possible to have overload for methods in WebAPI?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this.

You can't overload (based on a parameters type) a wepapi action methods having the same route.

You need to do somethig like this:

```
public void Send(string body, [FromUri] List<string> phoneNumber)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(body) || phoneNumber == null)
    {
        // return error message
    }

    if (phoneNumber.Count == 1 && phoneNumber[0].IndexOf(',') > -1)
    {
        var phonenumbers = phoneNumber[0]
        .Split(new []{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
        // execute method#1 and pass array of phonenumbers
    }
    else
    {
        // execute method#2 and pass list of phonenumbers
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution would be to use the **ActionName** attribute. An example:

```
[HttpGet]
[ActionName("SendWithPhoneNumber")
public void Send(string body, string phoneNumber)

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("SendWithPhoneNumbers")
public void Send(string body, [FromUri] List<string> phoneNumber)
```

You can also use [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) if you like. For more information have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353466/overload-web-api-action-method-based-on-parameter-type).