# Overlapping routes with WebApi

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to add a special route to the default WebApi sample:

The regular ones are

`/api/values` (retrieves all values)

`/api/values/{id}` (retrieves a specific value (by numeric id))

Now I want to add this api:

`/api/values/special`

The previous api (`/api/values/{id}`) should serve all requests with a numeric id, but `/api/values/special` should serve requests that call that specific url.

So far I got this for routing:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("SpecialValues", "api/values/special", new { controller = "values", action = "SpecialValues"  });
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

And this for implementation:

```
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/values
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET api/values/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST api/values
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT api/values/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE api/values/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }

    // GET api/values/special
    public IEnumerable<string> SpecialValues()
    {
        return new string[] { "special1", "special2" };
    }
}
```

But it will render: `The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'`.

If I call `/api/values/special` and I add `[HttpGet]` to the `SpecialValues` method it will work
but `/api/values` will stop working saying that there are multiple matching actions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The changes to WebApiConfig is not needed. Attach a `Route` attribute and a `HttpGet` attribute. You can read more about it [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2).

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/{controller}/special")]
public IEnumerable<string> SpecialValues()
{
    return new string[] { "special1", "special2" };
}
```

WebApiConfig -

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Attribute routing.
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        // Convention-based routing.
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: This results in the following message:

<Error>
<Message>The request is invalid.</Message>
<MessageDetail>
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.String Get(Int32)' in 'MvcApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>

It is still picked up by the Get method

Comment: Your WebApiConfig class should be as updated in my answer. Also the url that you are invoking should be like - `http://hostname:port/api/values/special`

Comment: Works like a charm, I had missed the part with MapHttpAttributeRoutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

yes, as mentioned above, attribute based routing is the only way to go here...

this post may also interests you
[Overload web api action method based on parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353466/overload-web-api-action-method-based-on-parameter-type)

Comment: This results in an error:

Multiple actions were found that match the request: Get on type MvcApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController Get on type MvcApplication1.Controllers.ValuesController