# ASP.net WebApi newly registered route says, that request is invalid

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, azure, asp.net-web-api

I'm setting up backend for my Windows Phone 8.1 App. I'm using **ASP.net WebApi** to create **RESTful** api for accessing data from DB, which is set up on **Windows Azure.**

This is how my routes looks:

```
 // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultNamedApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{name}",
            defaults: new { name = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

What i'm trying to achieve is accesing data using not an **integer** - I want to access data using a **string**.
This is code from my WebApi controller:

```
 private SmokopediaContext db = new SmokopediaContext();

    // GET api/Images
    public IQueryable<ImageModel> GetImageModels()
    {
        return db.ImageModels;
    }

    // GET api/Images/5
    [ResponseType(typeof(ImageModel))]
    public IHttpActionResult GetImageModel(int id)
    {
        ImageModel imagemodel = db.ImageModels.Find(id);
        if (imagemodel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        return Ok(imagemodel);
    }
    public IHttpActionResult GetImageModel(string name)
    {
        ImageModel imagemodel = db.ImageModels.Find(name);
        if(imagemodel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return Ok(imagemodel);
    }
    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    private bool ImageModelExists(int id)
    {
        return db.ImageModels.Count(e => e.ID == id) > 0;
    }
```

Most important code is an overload to **GetImageModel** with string parameter.

Server is returning error which says that parameter of url is incorrect:

```
<Error><Message>The request is invalid.</Message><MessageDetail>The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'id' of non-nullable type 'System.Int32' for method 'System.Web.Http.IHttpActionResult GetImageModel(Int32)' in 'Smokopedia.Controllers.DragonController'. An optional parameter must be a reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.</MessageDetail></Error>
```

What should I correct in my route?

Comment: Have you given us the correct controller? The error message says `DragonController` and `GetDragonModel` which you haven't posted.

Comment: Yes i did. I have only one controller, named DragonController, with two methods mentioned above.

Comment: So where is `GetDragonModel`?

Comment: So how do you expect us to help us by providing code from one controller and an error message from another?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I miss seen. I've pasted wrong code snippet. Of course I'm talking about ImageController

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no difference in URI template terms between `api/{controller}/{id}` and `api/{controller}/{name}`; the arbitrary names you assign to the parameters can't be used in resolving the route.

Take a look at [Overload web api action method based on parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353466/overload-web-api-action-method-based-on-parameter-type) for an example of how to "overload" routes based on parameter types.

Answer (score 3):

Use Attribute Routing:

```
[Route("api/Images/{id:int}")]     
public IHttpActionResult GetImageModel(int id){ do something}    

[Route("api/Images/{id}")]    
public IHttpActionResult GetImageModel(string id) {do something}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your url/query is important here.

You are probably using:

```
http://yourapp.address/<Controller>/<name>
```

That will not work in this registration. Your routing matches that address to first matching route. Ant that is *DefaultApi*. You must use

```
http://yourapp.address/<Controller>?name=<name>
```

or change Your routing.