# How to have a Route which points to two different controller end points which accepts different arguments in WEB Api 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

How to have a Route which points to two different controller end points which accepts different arguments in WEB Api 2
I have two different end points declared in controller and as for the REST  perspective I have to use the  alpha/{aplhaid}/beta format for both the end points ,

```
            [Authorize]
            [HttpPost]
            [Route("alpha/{aplhaid}/beta")]
            public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateAlpha(Beta beta, string projectId, [FromHeader] RevisionHeaderModel revision)

            [Authorize]
            [HttpPost]
            [Route("alpha/{aplhaid}/beta")]
            public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> CreateAlpha(List<Beta> betas, string projectId, [FromHeader] RevisionHeaderModel revision)
```

Is it possible to use the same router with different parameters which points to 2 different end points in Web API 2?

Comment: Have you tried using a IActionSelector? http://www.strathweb.com/2013/01/magical-web-api-action-selector-http-verb-and-action-name-dispatching-in-a-single-controller/

Comment: It wont help for this situation , arguments are the changing things

Comment: and how should look like a query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really need to have the **same route and the same ActionName**, you could do it with an `IHttpActionSelector`.

```
public class CustomActionSelector : ApiControllerActionSelector, IHttpActionSelector
{
    public new HttpActionDescriptor SelectAction(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        var context = HttpContext.Current;

        // Read the content. Probably a better way of doing it?
        var stream = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream);
        var input = stream.ReadToEnd();

        var array = new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<List<string>>(input);
        if (array != null)
        {
            // It's an array
            //TODO: Choose action.
        }
        else
        {
            // It's not an array
            //TODO: Choose action.
        }

        // Default.
        var action = base.SelectAction(controllerContext);
        return action;
    }

    public override ILookup<string, HttpActionDescriptor> GetActionMapping(HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor)
    {
        var lookup = base.GetActionMapping(controllerDescriptor);
        return lookup;
    }
}
```

In your WebApiConfig:

```
    config.Services.Replace(
        typeof(IHttpActionSelector),
        new CustomActionSelector());
```

Example for your an Controller:

```
public class FooController: ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(string id)
    {
        return "String";
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public string Post(List<string> id)
    {
        return "some list";
    }
}
```

The solution has some **big downsides**, if you ask me. First of, you should look for a solution for using this `CustomActionSelector` only when needed. Not for all controllers as it will create an overhead for each request.

I think you should reconsider why you really need two have to identical routes. I think readability will be suffering if the same route accepts different arguments. But that's just my opinion.

I would use different routes instead.

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry for the incomplete solution, but I hope it helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Overload `web api` action method based on parameter type is not well supported.
But what about `attribute based routing` ?

You can find out a good example [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)

Route constraints let you restrict how the parameters in the route template are matched. The general syntax is `"{parameter:constraint}"`. For example:

```
[Route("users/{id:int}"]
public User GetUserById(int id) { ... }

[Route("users/{name}"]
public User GetUserByName(string name) { ... }
```

And I think this link must be [helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353466/overload-web-api-action-method-based-on-parameter-type)

Comment: How do we do that for an HTTP Post ? Thank you but this is not applicable I guess

Comment: Only thing which is changing is the first argument an Alpha object to an alpha  list

Comment: @Kalanamith i asked on your question - Is it possible to use the same router with different parameters which points to 2 different end points in Web API 2?

Comment: What about using model like `class MyModel{ List<string> Strings }`

Comment: @Kalanamith actually I think your question isn't all clear for me, sorry by the way.

Answer (score 1):

Use one route and call the other controller inside from the first controller.