# Multiple actions were found that match the request api calling

Tags: c#

So I have had an old api call with this signature

```
public dynamic Add(String organizationId, String locationId, String orderType, String massTypeId, double amount, DateTime from, DateTime to, double distance, Driving driving)
```

Now I have changed to like this

```
public dynamic Add(String organizationId, String locationId, String orderType, String massTypeId, double amount, DateTime from, DateTime to, double distance, bool driving)
```

The only difference is the type of last parameter. For now I have to have my old api call until my apps are deployed. But if try it locally I get this error

> Multiple actions were found that match the request

In my data from client the last parameter looks like this

```
driving : true
```

I send data as JSON.

Does any body know why is it happening?

Comment: Did you change the signature or did you add a new method with just the slightly changed signature?

Comment: I added the new one with slightly changed signature. The new one takes the last param as boolean. But I still have to have the older one until my apps are up and running. Or the older versions won't be able to talk to new api.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple actions are found matching the request, 
It is better practice to use a a request object when you are migrating to new APIs. 
For using these two apis for now, you can specify a route name as decoration to be specific to your new route

```
[Route("MyNewApiAdd")]
public dynamic Add([FromBody]ReqObject req);
```

and define new

```
    public class ReqObject 
    {
    String organizationId{get;set;}
    String locationId{get;set;} 
    String orderType{get;set;}
    String massTypeId{get;set;}
    double amount{get;set;}
    DateTime from{get;set;}
    DateTime to{get;set;}
    double distance{get;set;}
    bool driving{get;set;}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this for Web API? If not, just ignore. If it is, I think what you are doing is not possible. What you did is overloading API methods which is not supported, instead you can have it like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353466/overload-web-api-action-method-based-on-parameter-type).

See sample:

```
[ActionName("GetById")]
public Foo Get(int id) { //whatever }

[ActionName("GetByString")]
public Foo Get(string id) { //whatever }

[ActionName("GetByGUID")]
public Foo Get(Guid id)  { //whatever }
```

Thanks!
[useAIble](http://useaible.com/code)

Comment: Why do you mention useAlXX?