# Base and derived classes within Web API Controller

Tags: rest, asp.net-web-api2

Let's say I have the following class structure:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string TestString { get; set; }
}
public class CityClass: BaseClass
{
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class TownClass:BaseClass
{
    public string Town { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a controller that has 2 post methods

```
public class TestController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post(TownClass model)
    {

    }

    public IHttpActionResult Post(CityClass model)
    {

    }

}
```

If I post to the end points with JSON data as follows:

```
http://localhost:30868/api/test

{"City":"New York","TestString":"Testing"}

or

{"Town":"Somewhere small","TestString":"Testing"}
```

I receive an error: Multiple actions were found that match the request

If there any way to get this working with the child/base class scenario?

I'd like to do this without defining new routes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Overload web api action method based on parameter type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14353466/overload-web-api-action-method-based-on-parameter-type)

Comment: That does not help

Comment: `If there any way to get this working with the child/base class scenario?` <= No. Even if the classes were unrelated it would still not work. By default you can't overload a web method based on the parameter type.