Overload action method in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC based on type of http body
I want to write some API with single URL and want to route based on body type like below
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{input: OverloadModelA}")]
    public IActionResult OverloadInsert([FromBody]OverloadModelA input)
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("{input: OverloadModelB}")]
    public IActionResult OverloadInsert([FromBody]OverloadModelB input)
    {
        return View();
    }

My models like below
public class OverloadModelA
{
    public string AName {  get; set; }
}

public class OverloadModelB
{
    public string BName { get; set; }
}

As I know from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14358642/1539100, I need route based on type like "{id:int}" (overload action method).
but "{input: OverloadModelA}" is not working and I get this error:

InvalidOperationException: The constraint reference ' OverloadModelA' could not be resolved to a type. Register the constraint type with 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.RouteOptions.ConstraintMap'.

How can I overload action method based on custom type?
I am using .NET 8

I found some solution based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/1045616/1539100 that using ActionMethodSelectorAttribute but I think it is very hard and inefficient solution, so I hope some one provide more better (clean and good performance) solution for my question.
