# Is it ok for a REST api to be exposed via two HTTP methods?

Tags: api, rest, search

The problem is that we have a complex query string for a search api and want to let the users have convenience of using body instead. So we want to allow both GET and POST(or PUT).

I understand that there will be a debate of search being a read only operation and it should be GET only as per REST standards. Also PUT is not cache friendly as i understand.
But i also know that its ok to deviate at times from the REST standards. But does it make sense to have two methods for client's convenience?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `POST` directly to query data is *not* a good thing, precisely for the reasons that you mentioned. If your search string is complex, perhaps you could simplify things by splitting the querying process in two steps - one involving a `POST`, and another one involving straight `GET`s.

The first step creates a query template using the `POST`. The query string is sent via message body, and becomes a new resource that users can query through `GET`. Query string allows for parameters, in a way similar to SQL queries. Taking a wild guess at how your query might look, here is an example:

```
(userName = $name) || (createdBefore > $asOf && deleted=false)
```

Your users would `POST` this in a message body, and get a new resource identifier back. This resource identifies a parameterized "view" into your data. Let's say the resource id for this view is `aabb02kjh`. Now your users can query it like this:

```
https://app.yourserver.net/aabb02kjh?name=airboss&asof=20140101
```

This adds some complexity to your API, but it lets users define and reuse query templates with very simple and standard query strings.

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight...I also came across this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering and made we wonder that for usability (to avoid complex search query strings) can we allow some RESTlessness :) i.e. to use POST instead of GET

Comment: @airboss Yes, the top answer from that thread talks about essentially the same thing.

Comment: I should accept this answer since its an interesting concept. The only issue is multiple calls but the advantage is having the query template defined. Probably no need to expose it as two HTTP methods, actually am not sure if its a good design to expose via two methods.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question. I mean by POST -> PUT,DELETE there are common workarounds for overriding HTTP methods:

- sending a `_method` hidden input field with the post data
- sending a `_method` query param in the URL
- sending an `X-HTTP-Method-Override` header with the post

etc... So if they are valid (I am not sure about that), then you could use the same approach by GET as well.

According to REST constraints: cache and the uniform interface, and the HTTP method definitions, you have to use GET by retrieval requests. There are only a few URL query languages to make URLs readable, for example RQL, but you can always pick your favorite query language and serialize it for URL usage...

Another interesting approach to add [link descriptions](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-wilde-link-desc-01) about the URL. (But that is very new for me either.)