# REST - breaking client by not supported MIME type or semantics (vocab)

Tags: rest

How can we help the REST client developers by processing the responses and creating the requests to the REST APIs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According the [code on demand (optional) constraint](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm#sec_5_1_7) we can send plugins to them. These plugins can contain code about how to parse a specific MIME type, or how to understand the semantics of our response. For example if we need a search query languge - like somebody [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25749060/boolean-logic-in-restful-filtering-and-queries) does - then we can write a new vocab for our query language and send a plugin to the clients. So with that plugin they will be able to understand the semantics of our query descriptions and build a query URL param using the description. By clients with GUI it is possible to generate input fields using the description. While there is not much talk about the code on demand constraint, it can be very useful to support the client developers...

I think we need a standard solution about how to install such plugins. By browsers an URL with a plugin link relation might be okay, however I have no experience with this approach yet.