# How to desing RESTful advanced search/filter

Tags: api, rest, search, filter

First of all, I have read [RESTful URL design for search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search) and [How to design RESTful search/filtering?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020704/how-to-design-restful-search-filtering) questions. I am trying to design more advanced options for searching in a simple and RESTful way.
The answers to those questions have given me some insight and clues on how to design my previous application url pattern for search/filter functionality.

First, I came up with quite nice and simple solution for basic filtering options, using pattern:

```
Equality search: key = val

IN search: key = val1 & key = val2
```

But as application has grown, so were the search requirements. And I ended up with some rather unpleasant and complex url pattern for advanced searching options which included:

```
Negation search: key-N = val

Like search: key-L = val

OR search: key1-O = val1 & key2 = val2

Range search: key1-RS = val1 & key1-RE = val2
```

Whats more, beside filters, query has to get information about pagination and order by, so the filter parameter has F- suffix, order by fields has O- suffix, and pagination has P- suffix.

I hope that at this point I do not have to add that parsing such request is rather malicious task, with the possibility of ambiguity if key will contain '-'. I have created some regexp to parse it, and it works quite well as for now, but...

Now I am starting to write a new web app and I have the chance to redesign this piece from scratch.

I am wondering about creating object in a browser containing all information in structured and self-explanatory way and send it to server as as JSON string, like:

```
filter = {{'type':'like','field':key,'value':val1,'operator':'and','negation':false},..}
```

But I get strange feeling that this is not good idea - I really don't know why.

So, this would be the definition of my context. Now the question:

I am searching for simpler and safer pattern for implementing advanced search including options I mentioned above as RESTful GET parameters - can you share some ideas?
Or maybe some insights on not doing this in a RESTful way?
Also, if you see some pitfalls in JSON way, please share them.

**EDIT:**

I know what makes sending json as get parameter, not so good idea. Encoding it - it makes it ugly and hard to read.

Info provided by links sended by thierry templier, gave me something to think about and I managed to design more consistient and safe filter handling in GET parameters. Below is definition of syntax.

For filters - multiple F parameters (one for each search criterium):

```
F = OPERATOR:NEGATION:TYPE:FIELD:VAL[:VAL1,:VAL2...]
```

allowed values:

```
[AND|OR]:[T|F]:[EQ|LI|IN|RA]:FIELD_NAME:VALUE1:VALUE2...
```

For order by - multiple O parameters (one for each ordered field):

```
O = ODINAL_NO:DIRECTION:FIELD
```

allowed values:

```
[0-9]+:[ASC|DESC]:FIELD_NAME
```

Pagination - single P parameter:

```
P = ITEMS_PER_PAGE:FROM_PAGE:TO_PAGE
```

I think this will be good solution - it meets all my requirements, it is easy to parse and write, it is readable and I do not see how that syntax can become ambiguous.

I wloud appreciate any thoughts on that idea - do you see any pitfalls?

Comment: So what did work out for you in the end? I am trying to implement a similar API right now and I am trying to find a way to represent "parentheses", for example (key1:value1 OR key2:value2) AND (key3:value3 OR key4:value4).

Comment: Yeah, it is working very well. 
Friend from work suggested using [polish notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation) for parentheses - it is easy to both create and parse, and fits nice to url query.
We implemented it in slighty modified way to that shown here in my work to be used with devextreme grid on frontend, be parsed to sql on .netCore middleware and send to either oracle and mssql database. It provides very easy way to rapidly produce fully functionable screen with grid from any sql query.

Comment: Thx, will try that!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are several options here. But it's clear that if your queries tend to be complex with operators, and so on... you can't use a set of query parameters. I see two approaches:

- Provide the query as JSON content to a method `POST`
- Provide the query in a query parameter with a specific format / grammar to a method `GET`

I think that you could have a look at what ElasticSearch for their queries. They are able to describe very complex queries with JSON contents (using several levels). Here is a link to their query DSL: http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html.

You can also have a look at what OData does for queries. They choose another approach with a single query parameter `$filter`. Here are some links that can give you some examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh169248(v=nav.70) and http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-3-0/url-conventions/. This option requires to have a grammar on the server side to parse your query.

In general, this link could also give you some hints at this level in its section "Filtering data": https://templth.wordpress.com/2014/12/15/designing-a-web-api/.

Hope it gives you some helpful hints to design your queries within your RESTful services ;-)

Thierry