# Which HTTP verb to use to get data based on complex input data

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-verbs

So if I would want to get say a User data, passing user id, I will use `GET` verb and pass user id in query string with route something like this

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("user/{userId}")]
```

But what if I want to fetch user based on multiple input parameters. Say by UserType, Salary etc.

Then passing these multiple values or complex object values in querystring will not make sense, I will have to pass them in body and for that I will have to use the `POST` verb.

But is it correct to use `POST` verb to get data?

If not, which verb should I use for these cases

Comment: This thread has some interesting input on this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29203447/managing-complex-data-with-get

Comment: @stuartd Yes, but is it correct to pass complex data in query string, that too is also wrong I guess. That is why I asked the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why nobody suggested me to use `FromBody` attribute with my parameter.

That way I do not have to change the api to `POST`.

I can use `GET` and still pass the parameter in the body.

Comment: The RFC standard for GET does not define a body, so using the FromBody attribute is the wrong approach.

Answer (score 2):

I would say it is ok to use `POST` in this situation. A query string that is too long can also cause problems when it comes to limits to the url length of webrowsers or servers.

But if you want to be correct about the verbs you could `POST` and create a filter object and return its `id`, then do your `GET` request including the `filterId`.

Your backend can now retrieve the previously created filter and apply it.