# Google Endpoint + Objectify + Android filter or search

Tags: android, rest, google-cloud-endpoints, objectify

I started with Objectify and Google endpoint.
I successfully went through adding module, generating endpoints i have client libraries, I can get, list, insert, remove, update results on android. But **I got stuck on filtering**. I read on objectify wiki that there is something like that possible:

```
List<Car> cars = ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("year >", 1999).list();
```

But problem is I cant get Objectify on android side. How can i achieve this. Can I even get it on android side?

I aslo read [RESTful URL design for search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search) i tried it and it worked but I would like to use objectify.

Also am not sure if I understand endpoints very well. Are they the only way to communicate with other side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I do understand endpoints better now. I created mehod on backend side eg

```
 @ApiMethod(name = "search")
public List<Car> search(//some params){
        return ofy().load().type(Car.class).filter("year >", 1999).list();
}
```

this works perfectly on client side I just call `myApi.search();`