# Should I allow user-provided values to be passed through a query string?

Tags: rest, url

I'm adding a search endpoint to a RESTful API. After reading [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/207477/restful-url-design-for-search), I'd like the endpoint to be designed like:

`GET /users?firstName=Otis&hobby=golf,rugby,hunting`

That seems like a good idea so far. But the values that I'll be using to perform the search will be provided by the user via a standard HTML input field. I'll guard against malicious injections on the server-side, so that's not my concern. I'm more concerned about the user providing a value that causes the URL to exceed the max URL length of [~2000 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers).

I can do some max-length validation and add some user prompts, etc, but I'm wondering if there's a more standard way to handle this case.

I thought about providing the values in the request body using `POST /users`, but that endpoint is reserved for new user creation, so that's out.

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Putting data in query string is discouraged specially when on shared computers. Do you have access to post processing endpoint? If so, you can send an extra parameter to have different behavior. Otherwise, you should create a new post endpoint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see these possible solutions:

1. not actually a solution. Go with the query parameter and accept the length constraints
2. go with the POST solution that shouldn't be designed as you mention. As you point out, if you POST a user to `.../users` you will create a new user entity. But this is not what you want to do. You want to submit a *search ticket* to the server that will return a list of results matching your criteria. I'll design something as such

   `POST .../search/users` passing in the body a representation of your search item
3. distribute the query both server side and client side. Say you have complex criteria to match. Set up a taxonomy of them so that the most strict ones are handled server side. Thus, the server is able to return a manageable list of items you can subsequently filter on the client side. In this approach you can save space in the query string by sending to the server only a subset of the criteria you want to meet in your search.